# Make load balancing server

Tags: apache, server, load-balancing, web-hosting

I manage a few websites on a shared hosting UNIX server with a hosting company and would like to create a load balancing server at home. It would take some of the traffic if it gets to heavy or a site goes down. I could get a dedicated hosting package but I want to save money. I know I would probably have to setup an Apache server and have the same files as I have with the hosting company but how do I route the traffic to the home server if the hosting company server times out? I am not too advanced when it comes to this stuff but I know how to install Apache, basic networking and basic web website languages like PHP. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are all boxes in the same local network?

Comment: No they are not. I assume the hosting company servers are somewhere in California and my home server(s) will be in Canada.